# cannot rollback - no transaction is active only if Angular server is started

Tags: mysql, angular, api, asp.net-core

I am following a tutorial for Angular with ASP.NET Core WebAPI. When my angular server is not started, I can send request to the API through Postman no problem. As soon as I start my angular server, I get the following stack trace:

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'cannot rollback - no transaction is active'.
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteDataReader.NextResult()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnectionExtensions.ExecuteNonQuery(SqliteConnection connection, 
String commandText, SqliteParameter[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteTransaction.RollbackInternal()
at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteTransaction.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
at System.Data.Common.DbTransaction.DisposeAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalTransaction.DisposeAsync()
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext _, ValueTuple`2 
parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 
entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at CoreApp.API.Data.CoreRepository.SaveAll() in X:\DEV\CoreApp\CoreApp.API\Data\CoreRepository.cs:line 113
at CoreApp.API.Helpers.LogUserActivity.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in X:\DEV\CoreApp\CoreApp.API\Helpers\LogUserActivity.cs:line 20
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
```

Another piece of info: if i try to open my DB in DB Browser and manully insert a row, it says

```
Error while saving the database file. no such savepoint: RESTOREPOINT (RELEASE "RESTOREPOINT";)
```

It seems that this behavior started suddenly and even though i try to delete the latest work i have typed, it still gives me this error. I also tried drop and recreate the DB a couple of times without success. I do not know how this error started or how to go about it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you show us the relative code, we might be able to help, but as it is you will only get guesses

Comment: What part of the code? I have multiple controllers or classes, I do not know which part would be actually relevant

Answer (score 0):

Just managed to make it work but I am not sure why.

The two errors seemed to be related to disk space according to search results. Even though my application was in a folder on the company network with plenty of space available, it might have been shocking on some disk issues. I copied the whole application folder on my local machine and it works just like it used to.